# Does column slice of a pandas dataframe with columns of different data types create a view or a copy?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some dataframes as follows:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2.0],[3,4.0]], index = ['row1','row2'], 
        columns = ['a','b'])
df2 = df.iloc[:, :]
df3 = df.iloc[:1, :]
df4 = df.iloc[:, :1]
```

Column `a` is int while column `b` is float.

### Question: are `df2, df3, df4` view or copy

#### test 1:

```
print(df._is_view, df._is_copy)
print(df2._is_view, df2._is_copy)
print(df3._is_view, df3._is_copy)
print(df4._is_view, df4._is_copy)
False None
False None
False <weakref at 0x7fed1113de90; to 'DataFrame' at 0x7fed11aa80a0>
True <weakref at 0x7fed114d65c0; to 'DataFrame' at 0x7fed11aa9ab0>
```

From this, it says `df2, df3` are not a view. But `df4` is.

Why?

#### test 2:

```
df2.loc['row1', 'b'] = 100.0
print(df1)
df3.loc['row1', 'a'] = 1000.0
print(df1)
df4.loc['row1', 'a'] = 10000.0
print(df1)

       a    b
row1  10  2.0
row2   3  4.0
        a    b
row1  100  2.0
row2    3  4.0
        a    b
row1  100  2.0
row2    3  4.0

/tmp/ipykernel_2006744/1832530048.py:5: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df4.loc['row1', 'a'] = 1000
```

From this, it can be seen that `df`'s value is updated when `df2` or `df3` is updated. So `df2` and `df3` should be a view.

Updating `df4` does not propagate to `df`, so `df4` seems to be a copy.

How come the results are contradicting to `_is_view`

### Question 2:

The `SettingWithCopyWarning` when setting `df4` says `a copy of a slice`. What is this refering to?

Is "a slice" refering to `df4`? Then what is the "a copy of a slice" provided I am using `.loc`?

Comment: Please study this https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy , you will get the idea why this is happening. This issue is mentioned in docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting values on a newly created sliced data frame. Don't do it. That's a kind of chained assignment, warned by [the document](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy).

In your code, the `df2` and `df3` are views and `df4` is a copy. It cannot be determined accurately from the undocumented API `_is_view` and `_is_copy`. And 'a copy of a slice' in the warning means the result of `df[:, :1]` as a copy, where 'a slice' means the symbolic source code `df[:, :1]` - a Python slicing syntax.

In the current Pandas implementation, it cannot be easily defined whether a slice of a data frame is a view or a copy of the original frame, due to the following reasons.

- Cell values of a data frame can be stored into multiple NumPy arrays.
  (See [The BlockManager](https://uwekorn.com/2020/05/24/the-one-pandas-internal.html) by Uwe for a detail.)
- Implementation on tracking references created by slicing is incomplete.
  (See [NDFrame._slice()](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d69e63d7b1e14b518a413fdff245e3329b92ceba/pandas/core/generic.py#L3998) for example. It does not check if an actual copy was done such as via `Block.take_nd()`.)

So the document says vaguely '... may depend on the context'. The `_is_view` and `_is_copy` do not give accurate information. And the internal checking for a chained assignment is not always done.

For example, you can see this incompleteness in the following.

```
print('on a heterogenious one')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [4, 5], 'c': ['a', 'b']})
df.iloc[:, :1].loc[0, 'a'] = 10

print('on a homogenious one')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [4, 5]})
df.iloc[:, :1].loc[0, 'a'] = 10
```

This outputs the following.

```
on a heterogenious one
on a homogenious one
test_iloc.py:10: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
...
```